# Is there a way to make the 3D cursor rotation follow the angle of an edge?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, 3d-cursor

I want my 3D cursor to share the same rotation as an edge of my mesh so that I can slide a vertex along that edge (using cursor setting under "**Transform Orientation**") but also past the extent of the edge (which the **Vertex Slide** operation is limited by).
This is among other reasons.

If there's a way to do this it would save me a lot of time when editing my meshes.

ty.

Comment: You can use 'c' to unclamp a vertex slide from the extents of its edge.  Begin slide along desired edge (to indicate edge to Blender), then hit c, then reverse the direction you're moving your mouse.  Your vertex will remain clamped to the line of the edge, but can travel further from its original neighbor.  There are also alternative techniques involving scaling from the adjoining vertex rather than sliding.